# JQuery's $.post with CSRF token in Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I am writing a Symfony2 website, in some cases, it interest me to post a few data through jquery (without creating an HTML form), like this:

```
function deleteNode(route, nodeIdToDelete){
$.post(route, { nodeId: nodeIdToDelete}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

}

The route and the controller and everything is created but the server is responding me:

> POST [route] 500 (Internal Server Error)

I suppose that the problem is the CSRF protection, so my questions are:

1. Is there anyway to use JQuery functions like $.post with some type of generated CSFR token from the controller or something like that?
2. I can disable CSRF protection only for THIS route?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For addressing Symfony routes from JavaScript please use FOSJsRoutingBundle.

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle